# vstest.console.exe error: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, vstest, vstest.console.exe

I have ran my test project from Test Explorer in Visual Studio 2022 and fortunately all tests passed. On the other side I'm trying to use **vstest.console.exe** to run **MyProject.Tests.build.appxrecipe** file but it's failing.

The log is the following:

```
The active test run was aborted. Reason: Unable to communicate with test host process.
Closing app with package full name 'b99a209c-7a2d-42fa-ba34-b16c8dee0379_1.0.0.0_x64__amhbm8v6a514r'.

Test Run Aborted with error System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.IO.Stream.ReadByte()
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadByte()
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.Read7BitEncodedInt()
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadString()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.LengthPrefixCommunicationChannel.NotifyDataAvailable()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.TcpClientExtensions.MessageLoopAsync(TcpClient client, ICommunicationChannel channel, Action`1 errorHandler, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---.
Total tests: Unknown
     Passed: 152
 Total time: 29.0509 Seconds
```

Something similar to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/2324).

Comment: I have the same error when calling **vstest.console.exe** in a Github Action.   Sometimes it works but most of the time it crashes on the last unit test to run, this can be any of the unit tests. I'm using .NET6 and "Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" v17.1.0.   
Did you find a solution?
My post is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71297998/github-action-calling-vstest-x86-takes-forever-or-fails-with-transport-connecti

Comment: I fought with this issue for a while - in our case, we had misunderstood xunit's test fixtures, and each test class was using 2 fixtures that set up `WebApplicationFactory` instances.  Presumably when they disposed, there was some shared dependency or something that caused the crash.  REALLY difficult to find though!

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed this issue upgrading two package refereces (MSTest.TestAdapter and MSTest.TestFramework) from 2.1.1 version to 2.2.8.